# How do I offset checker tiles in custom node group?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

How do I offset checker tiles, shown in the image where the offset is `0.5`?

Here is the checker node group.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Group input `Direction 0 = Horizontal` and `Direction 1 = Vertical` offset.

`Direction 0 = Horizontal` with an offset of `0.5`

[image]

`Direction 0 = Vertical` with an offset of `0.5`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Markus's answer and suggestions.

`Checker Node Group`

[image]

`Switch Node Group`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to get a row index and offset $x$ based on row index:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to have a scale at once, I want to Repeat X and Y separately and how can I change the offset direction?

Comment: @Karan can you make some sketches? Otherwise it's hard to understand what you mean. If it's just about the direction, surely it's not hard to figure out you can make the value negative for the opposite direction, and you can swap X and Y for vertical direction?

Comment: Currently, the offset is happening along the X-axis, I also want to have it along the Y-axis. Repeat X and Y means the number of checker tiles along the X and Y axis. The inputs are in the question above.

Comment: The offset should depend on the `Direction`, so `Direction = 0` means offsetting along the X-axis, and `Direction = 1`  means offsetting along the Y-axis.

Comment: @Karan duplicate the node setup, switch X and Y, control which branch you use using a mix node and a math: less than 0.5 node comparing the `Direction` and passing the result to Mix: Fac...

Comment: @karan, the initial question was clear "How do I offset checker tiles, shown in the image where the offset is 0.5?". Now you're adding details by editing your question. This is a bit unfair for Markus who took time to answer you. Thanks for your understanding.